# Why are delegates impersonating [delegation]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation

"Delegation" is a concept in access control, by which one user or role can permit its authority to be used by another authenticated identity or group.

So why does the tag wiki for [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delegation) talk about the unrelated concept of a "delegate" (bound function pointer)?

Can we claim [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delegation) back for the authorization concept, or if not, then edit the tag wiki to provide instruction on the appropriate tag for it, so that authorization questions such as these don't get mixed in with unrelated stuff?

- [Domain-wide delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329895/domain-wide-delegation)
- [Double hop SQL delegation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215982/double-hop-sql-delegation-not-working)
- [WCF Custom Delegation/Authentication without Kerberos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770550/wcf-custom-delegation-authentication-without-kerberos)
- [How can i start a console application using the 'network service' account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369527/how-can-i-start-a-console-application-using-the-network-service-account)
- [Accessing the data of other users using access delegation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267239/accessing-the-data-of-other-users-using-access-delegation-in-android)

---

There is also a concept of "interface delegation" often called "forwarding" and related to COM "aggregation" and inheritance.  This is not  closely related to either authorization or bound function pointers.  I could certainly understand if the [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delegation) tag is given to this use, but all the "delegate"/bound function pointer questions are in dire need of retagging to [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delegate).

---

In summary:

1. Bound function pointer questions need to be retagged to [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delegate)
2. The tag wiki for [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delegation) needs to be rewritten to explicitly cover one of the two competing correct uses of "delegation" (either access control delegation or interface delegation)
3. The tag wiki should point people interested in bound function pointers to [tag: delegate], and people interested in the looser meaning of "delegation" to the proper tag for that meaning.

Comment: Are you sure this would have the desired effect? Remember, users don't read tag excerpts/wiki. If there's misuse it will continue after the tag wiki changes.

Comment: @Braiam: But at least there would be clear guidance to the people trying to sort out the mess.  Right now the guidance is wrong, so sorting cannot even begin.

Comment: Well, who actually would do this sorting? Remember, that users can and will use any tag they deem relevant. And someone will see that the tag excerpt doesn't reflect usage and we will be back to square one.

Comment: @Braiam: Then why do we bother to have tag excerpts at all?  Your comments here are unconstructive.  User moderators *do* retag, and collecting a consensus on tag usage is the first step.

Comment: "Then why do we bother to have tag excerpts at all?" to guide those rare guys that actually read them. I'm an optimist. There must be some of those.

Comment: @Braiam: For the sake of the rare guys who read them before asking questions, and for the sake of experts setting their subscriptions, we should fix this.